# restrict xulrunner network access

Tags: firefox, xpcom, xulrunner

I have a xulrunner application that uses browser component to display HTML content. For security reasons I would like to restrict that browser to be able to only access a certain url mask. 
I would like to restrict any networking to intranet only, something like "*.company.com". But not only page navigation, XHR, CSS, script and all the netwoking.

Does any body know how to implement this? Any XPCOM components that I could use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be through a [proxy auto-configuration file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) (assuming that your application doesn't actually need to use a proxy). So you would set `network.proxy.type` preference to 2 (use PAC file) and `network.proxy.autoconfig_url` to `chrome://.../proxy.js`. With `proxy.js` being something along the lines of:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.company.com"))
    {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    return "SOCKS localhost:19191";
}
```

So any requests to `*.company.com` won't use a proxy whereas requests to other hosts will be directed to a localhost port which is hopefully closed - so these requests will not succeed. This is a hack of course but one that is simple enough and works well in most scenarios.

The proper (but more complicated) way of doing this would be using [content policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#Content_Policy). You need to implement [nsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy) in an XPCOM component and register that component in the `content-policy` category. This will make sure that the `shouldLoad()` method of your component will be called for each URL to be loaded - you can return `Ci.nsIContentPolicy.REJECT_REQUEST` to block the load.